# Get specific attribute value from xml in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse following XML using Java.

```
    <connection inherit="true" name="test">
      <ConnectionDetails>
        <conn name="domainname1.net">
            <prop name="dom-test" tags="1-test, con"/>
        </conn>
        <conn name="domainname2.net">
            <prop name="dom-test" tags="2-test, con"/>
        </conn>
        <conn name="domainname3.net">
            <prop name="dom-org" tags="org, con"/>
        </conn>
        <conn name="domainname4.net">
            <prop name="dom-test" tags="3-test"/>
        </conn>
        <conn name="domainname5.net">
           <prop name="dom-org" tags="org"/>
        </conn>
      </ConnectionDetails>
 </connection>
```

I have wrote Java code like :

```
File inputFile = new File("test.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("conn");
```

What I need is:

> - To get all connection with tag that contains the text "test"
>          - domainname1.net, domainname2.net, domainname4.net

Please help!

Comment: That's invalid XML. Without the first line it works fine.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Works fine for me. What's the problem?

Comment: No what I need is: to get that particular details (<conn name="domainname5.net">) with tags="1-test", 2-test etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression query = xPath.compile("//prop[contains(@tags, 'test')]/../@name");
NodeList nList = (NodeList)query.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

If you prefer a more manual approach (or you don't want the overhead of XPath), you can do this:

```
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("prop");
for (int i = 0, len = nList.getLength(); i < len; i++) {
    Element elm = (Element)nList.item(i);
    if (elm.getAttribute("name").contains("test")) {
        String connName = ((Element)elm.getParentNode()).getAttribute("name");
        // ...
    }
}
```